# How do I see how much space I'm using in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I seem to be having a space issue with my webhost provider. I'm using the most recent version of Wordpress and they use MySQL v5.6. When I goto phpmyadmin I see this:

```
Database    Collation   Tables  Rows    Data    Indexes Total
db11_wrd11  latin1_swedish_ci   40  24,274  5.9 MiB 1.9 MiB 7.8 MiB
Total: 1    latin1_swedish_ci   40  24,274  5.9 MiB 1.9 MiB 7.8 MiB
```

When I goto my database manager from my web host, it says I'm using 325.77 out of 300 MB. They want me to upgrade to a larger package however I think this is an error and think I need verify this as I'm thinking of switch providers. How can I check how much I'm using? I do have access to my DB via SSH.

Update 1:

Here is the result of SHOW TABLE STATUS, since I don't know how to post the results inline here is a screen shot. https://snag.gy/gyZ3nd.jpg

Comment: `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.

Comment: I did a OPTIMIZE TABLE and that have seemed to have helped with the space issue. Although phpmyadmin still only shows I'm using less than 8MB the control panel now says im using 45MB

Answer (score 1):

From PHP admin, try to run this query.  It should give you the size in MB of your DBs.

```
 SELECT 
    table_schema "DB Name", 
    Round(Sum(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB" 
 FROM   
    information_schema.tables 
 GROUP  BY 
    table_schema;
```

Comment: This shows me the same thing from what enable statistics tell me, that I'm using a total of 7.8MB.

Comment: So maybe your host is talking about your web storage too.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: They have separated and I do show that I have available disk space.

Comment: I would switch then. How much are you paying?